# Kendo UI Grid Issue in core

Tags: kendo-ui, asp.net-core-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Issue in using Kendo Grid Column Template in .Net Core, works fine in .net mvc

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Model>().Method()
.Columns(c => {
  c.Template(m => null).Title("").Width(10)
  .ClientTemplate();
})
```

Error in m => null: Cannot convert lambda expression to type string because it is not a delegate type

Please help

Comment: Can't you remove the `Template(m => null)` ?

Comment: I tried one of the suggestion in telerik forum which worked and that is to have the line replaced with c.Bound("").Title("").Width(10).ClientTemplate();

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown By the way why do you suggest this? I am very new to UI and Kendo can you please suggest the reason behind? What should I have within template if I have something in Title? I am sorry if my questions are basic or not making much sense

Comment: The reason is: if you dont need a template, you just dont use the method `Template()`, dont need to set the template as `null`.

Comment: What do I do in case of: c.Template(m=>null).Title("Name").Width(100).ClientTemplate("")